# Browser doesn't show image from Laravel storage

Tags: php, laravel, storage, laravel-8, laravel-sail

I'm using **Laravel 8** with **Docker** on Windows 10 through **WSL2** and **Sail**. I created a CRUD to store some articles with images in my DB.  I'm trying to show images from laravel storage, but they are not appearing in the browser.  How can I fix this?

ArticleController.php

```
    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('admin.articles.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required',
            'author' => 'required',
            'image' => 'nullable | image | max:1024'
        ]);

        $image = Storage::put('images', $request->image); 
        $validatedData['image'] = $image;

        Article::create($validatedData);

        return redirect()->route('admin.articles.index');
    }
```

I followed the [Laravel 8 docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#introduction) to storage my images using the public disk.

filesystem.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default filesystem disk that should be used
    | by the framework. The "local" disk, as well as a variety of cloud
    | based disks are available to your application. Just store away!
    |
    */

    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'public'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Filesystem Disks
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you
    | may even configure multiple disks of the same driver. Defaults have
    | been setup for each driver as an example of the required options.
    |
    | Supported Drivers: "local", "ftp", "sftp", "s3"
    |
    */

    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Symbolic Links
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the symbolic links that will be created when the
    | `storage:link` Artisan command is executed. The array keys should be
    | the locations of the links and the values should be their targets.
    |
    */

    'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    ]
];
```

I also created the link with the command line `sail artisan storage:link`
Everything work well, because I can see the image in the right path: `storage/app/images/my_image` as follow:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UntDH.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFfDy.png)

I have a problem when I try to show my image in the laravel blade as follow:

```
<div class="flex justify-center flex-wrap">
    @foreach ($articles as $article)
        {{-- Articles --}}
        <div class="max-w-sm rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg my-5 mx-2">
            <img class="w-full" src="{{ asset( 'storage/' . $article->image) }}" alt="article_image">
            <div class="px-6 py-4">
                <div class="font-bold text-xl mb-2">
                    {{ $article->title }}
                </div>
                <p class="text-gray-700 text-base overflow-hidden h-16">{{ $article->body }}</p>
                <span class="inline-block bg-gray-200 rounded-full px-3 py-1 mt-3 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-700">{{ $article->author }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

I think the problem is on the path because on the browser i can see that:
`<img class="w-full" src="http://localhost/storage/images/9D1GCN9XDEwRWq8zN2wiA6eBSazgg657f9uUs0Uj.png" alt="article_image">` and the image is not shown.

I  tried everything, change the filesystem, change the path storage into the controller etc etc.. but I can't find a solution.

Comment: You are storing the image at storage/app/images/ so you need to use this path also in asset('storage/images/'.$article->image) (just without the app)

Comment: on what port your app is running ?

Answer (score 7):

As the image path in the browser looks right, I think is a problem with the symbolic link to the public directory generated with `sail artisan storage:link`.

I had the same problem and solved it running `php artisan storage:link`from inside the container.

To me, the solution was making the link directly inside the container, not through sail.

```
# Get inside the container. Replace "your-project-container" with the actual name.
docker exec -it your-project-container /bin/sh
# Change to user sail
su sail
# Run artisan storage:link
php artisan storage:link
# Exit twice to get out the container
exit
exit
```

Doing `sail artisan storage:link` creates a wrong link with a non existing /var/www/html path outside the container.

Comment: Hi @Bolorino, i have tried your method, but it does not seem to be working. It says `The [/var/www/html/public/storage] link has been connected to [/var/www/html/storage/app/public].`
`The links have been created.`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should put `get()`

```
$image = Storage::put('images', $request->image->get());
```

If you don't define the disk like:

```
Storage::disk('public')->put('images', $request->image->get());
```

it will be in default disk ("local"). And to retrieve maybe you can put like:

```
<img class="w-full" src="{{ Storage::url('storage/' . $article->image) }}" alt="article_image">
```

A better approach would be:

```
$path = "image_" . time() . '.' . $request->image->extension();
Storage::disk('public')->put($path, $request->image->get());
Article::create([...,
   'image'=>$path,
]);
```

Retrieve

```
<img class="w-full" src="{{ Storage::url($article->image) }}" alt="article_image">
```